# No se visualizan las tablas de la base de datos en el panel de control de django

Tags: python, base-de-datos, django, linux, ubuntu

Esta es mi primer consulta, espero formularla bien.

Estoy realizando mi primera aplicación django en un servidor de linux, ubuntu 20, la aplicación está en online, pero al ingresar al panel de control de administrador, no puedo ver las tablas creadas:

Tengo los modelos creados en el archivo "models" de la aplicación:

```
from django.db import models
   
class Pedidos(models.Model):
    numero = models.IntegerField()
    fecha = models.DateField()
    entregado = models.BooleanField()

class Materiales(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key = True)
    descripcion_material = models.CharField('Descripcion del material', max_length = 255, blank = False, null = False)
    unidad_de_medida = models.CharField('Unidad de medida', max_length = 2, blank = False, null = False)
    descripcion_presentacion = models.CharField('Descripcion de la unidad de medida', max_length = 255, blank = False, null = False)
    cantidad_presentacion = models.IntegerField('Cantidad en UM.', blank = False, null = False)
    unidad_de_medida_base = models.CharField('Unidad de medida base', max_length = 2, blank = False, null = False)
```

Tengo registrados los modelos en la aplicación, en el archivo admin:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Pedidos, Materiales

admin.site.register(Materiales)
admin.site.register(Pedidos)
```

Tengo esta configuración sobre la base de datos en settings del programa:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'compass',
        'USER': 'leonardo',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

y realizo las migraciones a la base de datos de la siguiente manera:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Haciendo lo mismo en mi computadora personal, levantando el server con:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

y modificando la información de la base de datos de settings:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': "compass",
        'USER': "leonardo",
        'PASSWORD': "#password",
        'HOST':'127.0.0.1',
        'DATABASE_PORT':'5432',
    }
}
```

Funciona correctamente, puedo ver en el panel de control las tablas, y modificarlas (En ambos casos el usuario tiene permisos de superusuario)

en la aplicación que tengo en el servidor, no puedo ver las tablas y modificarlas, pero si me dirijo a la sección de usuarios > permisos, me figuran las tablas para darlas como permisos (si las asigno igualmente no figuran)

[image: panel control]

Puedo ver una diferencia con la sección de permisos de la aplicación en mi computadora, (en donde funciona correctamente)

[image: panel de control ok]

Gracias por su tiempo, y espero que alguno me pueda guiar, llevo un buen tiempo intentando entender el problema.

(reinstale la base de datos, el repositorio, la migración la hice en el servidor, y luego probé hacerla en mi computadora personal, donde funcionaba, y llevar el repositorio al servidor)

ACTUALIZACIÓN
**IMPORTANTE!!: Ejecutando python manage.py runserver en el servidor funciona correctamente, por lo que el inconveniente no es el código ni la base de datos, podría ser gunicorn o nginx y su configuración**

Comment: Verifica que al momento de iniciar el servidor, estes en el directorio padre de la aplicacion que estas haciendo